# Django crispy form, hide/show fields in the template

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

i'm using Crispy-Form and Bootstrap within Django. It works very well.
Now, i would like to have a field showing only when another field has input.
Basically i've a `multpile select list` called A  visible, and a `text field`, B, hidden.
once the the user focus/select one or more value in A, B should become visible. And if none are selected it should become invisible.

Does cripsy form have this feature or the possibility to write the JS?
Or do i've to write the JS in the html page where the form is rendered?

ciao

Answer (score 4):

I've done something similar once. I assigned a class 'hidden' to the inputs that you want to be initially hidden. This can be done by nesting the fields in a Div, and assigning a css_class. See http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects

Then use javascript to remove the 'hidden' class when a certain action occurs.

If you decide to use jQuery, you can use the following function:
$("input[name='a_hidden_field']").removeClass('hidden')

Comment: ok, so far what i did is writing Jquery functions. But i was courious if crispy form has the possibility to hide/show fields based on input values.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then I don't think that is possible. I believe you need to rely on javascript or jQuery to do the hiding and showing of fields. What you can do is have javascript find take notice of the input value, and show fields accordingly. A usecase of this would be that if you have radio buttons, you could display a specific fields based on which radio button is selected. The same goes for all other kinds of input.